Raspberry pi cannot ssh
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 4gb ram and I installed Raspberry OS lite 64-bit on it. I then sshed into it and realized I didn't know the password that was set(I believe I know what it was now). I then reformatted and reimaged the sd card. I cannot SSH into it anymore using Putty, it gives me an error: "Network error: Software caused connection abort." I have tried many things except editing the files of my Raspberry Pi. I also pinged the IP and it was successful. SSH was enabled in the setup as well. I even restarted the device.

If UFW was enabled, make sure you allow SSH.

For me, it looks like a configuration issue. You could try :
systemctl status ssh

To ensure that your ssh service is active, running and if it is enabled. If it's not then when you restart your device it will be disabled. To enable it :
systemctl enable ssh

You should also check if ssh connection is authorized by checking your interfaces options:
sudo raspi-config

Finally, if it still not working, your issue could come from your sshd config, please double check your
/etc/ssh/sshd_config file and make sure everything is good.

all of this was not possible due to the fact that I was unable to access the raspberry pi. The only thing that worked was buying a mini hdmi cable and simply plugging it in. That somehow fixed the issue. If I booted the raspberry pi with the hdmi cable plugged in then ssh would be activated, without it no ssh.
